# Bootstrap Navbar background-image repeat issue on small resolutions

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have this problem with BS Navbar with background image. Despite i've set `background-repeat: repeat-x;` in my CSS, the bgimage still appears on first link in dropdown menu. Heres the CSS:

```
.paanavi {
    background-image: url(../../kuvat/bg_navi.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: F9B03A;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 50px;
}

.container-fluid > .navbar-collapse, 
.container-fluid > .navbar-header,
.container > .navbar-collapse,
.container > .navbar-header {
    height: auto;
    background-image: url(../../kuvat/bg_navi.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: #F9B03A;
}
```

And heres what it looks like on "mobile resolution":

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68mvq.jpg)

How can i fix this?

Comment: Great question! Can you add the corresponding html part? That way people may help you a lot easier and you'll likely receive better answers.

Comment: try media query and give a max height to the bg.